# Is it possible to use if/else condition in for loop?

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to use an `if`/`else` statement in `for` loop, but I keep encountering syntax errors saying "Unexpected".

What is a proper syntax for using `if`/`else` statement in a `for` loop?

```
module onezerocheck(in,out);
input [31:0] in;
output out;
integer i;   //1101
reg j;
always@(in) begin
    for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1) begin
        if(in[i]==0) begin
            j=1;
            out=1'b0;
        end

        else if(in[i]==1) begin
            j=0;
            out=1'b0;   
        end          

        else if((if[i]==1&&j==1)) begin //unexpected if
            out=1'b1;
            j=0;
        end

        else if((if[i]==1&&j==0)) begin //unexpected else
            out=1'b0;
            j=0;
        end     
    end //unexpected end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of errors.

`if` is a reserved keyword in Verilog, and it can not be used as a variable name.  You likely want to replace `if[i]` with `in[i]` in both places.

Also, you need to declare `out` as a `reg` since it is assigned in an `always` block.

```
module onezerocheck(in,out);
input [31:0] in;
output out;
reg out;
integer i;   //1101
reg j;
always@(in) begin
    for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1) begin
        if(in[i]==0) begin
            j=1;
            out=1'b0;
        end

        else if(in[i]==1) begin
            j=0;
            out=1'b0;   
        end          

        else if((in[i]==1&&j==1)) begin //unexpected if
            out=1'b1;
            j=0;
        end

        else if((in[i]==1&&j==0)) begin //unexpected else
            out=1'b0;
            j=0;
        end     
    end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score -1):

*Try this:*

```
module onezerocheck(in,out);
input [31:0] in;
output out;
integer i;   //1101
reg j;
always@(in) 
begin
    for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1) 
    begin
        if(in[i]==0) 
        begin
            j=1;
            out=1'b0;
        end

        else if(in[i]==1) 
        begin
            j=0;
            out=1'b0;   
        end          

        else if((in[i]==1)&&(j==1)) 
        begin 
            out=1'b1;
            j=0;
        end

        else if((in[i]==1)&&(j==0)) 
        begin
            out=1'b0;
            j=0;
        end
        else
        begin
        //else statement here
        end     
    end 
end
endmodule
```